# PL/SQL Oracle wallet and request for invoke HTTPS WS UTL_HTTP

Tags: oracle, web-services, https, wallet

We have the next pl/sql Oracle code:

`42 UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/home/oracle/admin/wallet/GOBDATDBDDES', '*****'); 43 req := utl_http.begin_request(url,'POST');`

I ofuscated the pass.

When I execute the pl, this error appears:

`ORA-29273: fallo de la solicitud HTTP ORA-28759: fallo al abrir el archivo ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", línea 380 ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_HTTP", línea 1148 ORA-06512: en "GOBDAT_ORS.MDM_CONSUME_FS_SERVICES", línea 43`

Where i can see the error in line 43 when i begin the request.

Thanks in advance.

I execute the PL but crashed with the indicated error.

Comment: Please run `alter session set nls_language = american;` to get an English error message.

Comment: Can you verify the path to the wallet? The path should be to the directory that contains the file that ends with .sso. On your database server you should be able to find the wallet and display the content with `orapki wallet display -wallet /home/oracle/admin/wallet` (if that is the correct path).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! when we add a certificate to the Oracle wallet, we must see the intermediate certificates from the ROOT Certificate.. if you add all the certificates to the wallet, this run :).